# How can I render google map with google.maps.Map result

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to render `google map` in div,it is in `modal`(while modal open time, compiling the handlebars template,so what I mean `div` is in template).These `model` will open once the user click on button.After making the map,saving `mapInstance` in model.So If I want to place marker I will get the mapInstance from model.For this I written the following code

```
  var mapStyles={mapOptions:/*options of map*/}

 var el = document.getElementById("locationGmap");
  if (chartsModelObj.get("locationMapInstance")==="") {
    //checking whether user with this feature initial time or not      
    var mapInstance=new google.maps.Map(domEle, mapStyles.mapOptions);
    chartsModelObj.set("locationMapInstance",mapInstance);
  };
```

while first click event of `button`,map is appearing and storing the instance in model.So first click event time it's working fine.But at second click event of `button`,I am re-templating the elements(what are appearing in modal) because of this `map` was not appearing(second time I don't want create instance,I want to use old instance.).

For reference I attached following screenshots

First click Event:

[image]

After First click event(Second,third,....):

[image]

I have a old mapIstance in model.I tried to set in the following way.I am getting the wrong way, I attached screenshot also.

```
 var map=chartsModelObj.attributes.locationMapInstance;
 el.innerHTML=map;
```

[image]

How can I render map with old mapInstance.

Thanks.

Comment: the map is rendered inside the html when constructed, if you store the map object it is yes an object, as you see in the last code block you have posted, but if you do not call the constructor the map is not rendered inside the html element. IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve your problem by creating the map once in a hidden `<div>`, and then move the map around to where you want it shown, when you want to show it (also works on modals)

See this working demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/k6d7D/**

the google map is created on a `<div>` with `display: none;`

In the example I move the map to the `<div>` clicked :

```js
function moveMap() {
    map.style.display='block';
    this.appendChild(map); 
    google.maps.event.trigger(googleMap, 'resize');
}
map2.onclick = moveMap;
map3.onclick = moveMap;
```

The most important thing here is to trigger the `resize`-event, so the map is redrawn properly. You dont show so much code, so really cant place the above into the right context according to your question, but I am sure you can manage to get it to work.